# React-navigation bar not displaying

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to React-native and am trying to create scenes for my app. I am having trouble with two things: Firstly, I can't understand why the navigation bar with the title is not showing. I am using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). Secondly, I don't know whether the way I have started developing the app is correct.

**Index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Hola', () => App);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import Hola from './src/ConversationListScreen';
import styles from './src/styles';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Hola/>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**src/ConversationListScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class ConversationListScreen extends Component
{
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Hola',
    };
    render() {
        return <Text>Hello, Navigation</Text>;
    }
}

export const Hola = StackNavigator({
    ConversationList: { screen: ConversationListScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ConversationListScreen', () => Hola);
```

Comment: Did you try removing `View` component wrapping `Hola` in `App` component?

Comment: Also you should register only one component. `AppRegistry.registerComponent('ConversationListScreen', () => Hola);` is unnecessary.

Comment: You mean just removing `<View></View>`

Comment: Yes. Try removing `View` and second `AppRegistry`

Comment: Nopes, didn't work. Am still only getting the `Hello, Navigation` text.

Comment: Did you removed the second `AppRegistry`?

Comment: Yes, I did as you said. I have removed `View` component and also `AppRegistry.registerComponent('ConversationListScreen', () => Hola);`

Comment: Ok now change `import Hola from './src/ConversationListScreen';` to `import { Hola } from './src/ConversationListScreen';`

Comment: Yes! That fixed it. Could you explain what just happened? Plus could you comment on the structure or the way I have started developing the app. Is it feasible to maintain in the long run like this?

Comment: Sure. In your `ConversationListScreen.js` file you exporting 2 things. One is default. When importing if you don't use `{}` it will import the default exported object/constant, if you use `{}` you specify an exact object/constant to import. I suggest you to read more about import/export to understand whats going on better.

Comment: Ok! I will give it a read. :) Thank you.

Comment: @bennygenel, just one more question. What to do if I add another screen and how?

Comment: That a bit too broad to answer. Do some reading and follow up some tutorials. Basically you need to create another Component and then add it to your stack.

Comment: I did, but somehow its says that its duplicate. Can I discuss it in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156468/discussion-between-bennygenel-and-ayan).